# c# check logged users on network

Tags: c#, networking

How to query all PC's in the network to see who's actually logged on. I need to get list of "IPAddress + LogedUserName".

I am getting the list of computers that are available on LAN by this way:

```
using (DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:"))
        {
            foreach (DirectoryEntry computers in root.Children)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryEntry computer in computers.Children)
                {
                    if ((computer.Name != "Schema"))
                    {
                        textBox1.Text += computer.Name + "\r\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But I want to have also the name of logged user on each available computer.

Comment: Are you on a domain? You need to provide a lot more details, as is, the question is very likely to be closed.

Comment: edited the question, is it better? I want check range of IP adresses to availability of the computer, get its name and get currently loged username..

Comment: A lot better, I voted to reopen.

Comment: I can't answer but you may be able to do it with the library [Cassia](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/). I use it a lot and it works well. It is a .NET wrapper around the API calls for Terminal Services.

Answer (score 1):

Now that your question was re-opened here is a more full explanation of using [cassia](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/). This may or may not work on desktops that do not have RemoteDesktop enabled. This code is totally untested, it likely needs some fixes before it will work 100%, but it will get you on the right track.

```
using (DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:"))
{
    ITerminalServicesManager tsm = new Cassia.TerminalServicesManager();

    foreach (DirectoryEntry computers in root.Children)
    foreach (DirectoryEntry computer in computers.Children)
    {
        if ((computer.Name != "Schema"))
        {
            string linqCapture = computer.Name; //<-- This may not be necessary, 
                                                //but I have always have had bad
                                                //experiences with LINQ and foreach
                                                //loops not capturing the current
                                                //value of the variable correctly.

            //remove the last Where clause if you want all users connected 
            //to the computer, not just the one where it is the console session.
            foreach(var session in tsm.GetSessions(linqCapture)
                                      .Where(s => s.ConnectionState == ConnectionState.Active)
                                      .Where(s => s.ClientName == linqCapture))
            {
                string LoggedInUser = session.UserName;
                System.Net.IPAddress LoggedInIp = session.ClientIPAddress;
                //Do with data what ever you want to;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Scott Chamberlain,I have a same question and i thought your answer is my solution so i tried your code but it does not return any thing! Do'nt you have any suggestion? should this code run on a server?

Comment: I would open a new question showing exactly what you did and any error messages you got in the process. Be sure to include what version of .NET and what OS you are running your program on.

Comment: I had asked my question already in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302861/getting-a-list-of-every-active-computers-on-the-network but no one answered.please help me...